# String manipulation in a bookmarklet not behaving as in console

Tags: javascript, regex, string, google-chrome, bookmarklet

In Google Chrome console, this works (it says the pop-up was blocked, but don't mind that now)

```
open('http://www.bugmenot.com/view/'+(escape(location).replace(/^\w+%3a\/\//i,'').replace(/\/.*/i,'')));
```

The pop-up is opened at `http://www.bugmenot.com/view/thesite.com`

Now, this doesn't work as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:open('http://www.bugmenot.com/view/'+(escape(location).replace(/^\w+%3a\/\//i,'').replace(/\/.*/i,'')));
```

Instead of opening the exact same URL, it opens `http://www.bugmenot.com/view/http%3A`.

**Why?**

Comment: Re: *A happy developer. But I love something more than code* - she is not something, but **somebody**!

Comment: @Ωmega Man, you're right! I've got to re-phrase that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
javascript:open('http://www.bugmenot.com/view/'+(escape(location).replace(/^.*?\/\/([^\/]*).*$/i, "$1")));
```

Comment: You should use as simple pattern as possible. Good luck!

Comment: So you're telling me you also have no idea :(

Comment: @CamiloMartin - When I saw you are using two `replace`, I just came with one simple... I haven't tested yours... There might be some special character in the string, or `%` is a problem here, or... If you want to play, try `.*%3a` or `.*\%3a` (without `^`), what it will do with that...

Comment: Same result using that :( It works in the console, but the result is different from the URL bar/bookmarklet on Chrome. To make it even more weird, `javascript:alert(escape(location))` alerts the exact same string on both.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused because `%3a` gets interpreted as a `:` in the URL bar or a bookmarklet.

```
javascript:alert('%3a');
```

Will be interpreted as

```
javascript:alert(':');
```

And so will this value on a regex, and related consequences will ensue.